# Finding mutual friend in one way relationship table

Tags: mysql

want mysql query for finding mutual friend between two friend but
I am maintain the friendship of user in one way relationship for ex.

first is users table

```
id  name
1   abc
2   xyz
3   pqr
```

Now second table is friend

```
id user_id friend_id
1   1      2
2   1      3
3   2      3
```

Now here i can say that abc(id=1) is friend of xyz(id=2) now similar way the xyz is friend of abc but now i want to find mutual friend between abc(id=1) and xyz(id=2) that is pqr so I want mysql query for that.

Comment: I think the problem is how to create a query that can determine that 3 (pqr) if a friend of both 1 (abc) and 2 (xyz)

Comment: @Francis Fuerte: that was my understanding as well.

Comment: this is actually a good question.. but poorly constucted due to the samples :)

Comment: @FrancisFuerte :hey francis i just started using stackoverflow so sorry for my question format next time i'll be careful

Comment: nah its no problem at all.. its just some people dont have the time to stop and absorb ambigious examples.. thats why you got downvoted :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REVISED**

This query will consider the "one way" relationship of a row in the friend table to be a "two way" relationship.  That is, it will consider a friend relationship: `('abc','xyz')` to be equivalent to the inverse relationship: `('xyz','abc')`.  (NOTE: we don't have any guarantee that both rows won't appear in the table, so we need to be careful about that. The `UNION` operator conveniently eliminates duplicates for us.)

This query should satisfy the specification:

```
SELECT mf.id
     , mf.name
  FROM (
         SELECT fr.user_id AS user_id
              , fr.friend_id AS friend_id
           FROM friend fr
           JOIN users fru
             ON fru.id = fr.user_id
          WHERE fru.name IN ('abc','xyz')
          UNION
         SELECT fl.friend_id AS user_id
              , fl.user_id AS friend_id
           FROM friend fl
           JOIN users flf
             ON flf.id = fl.friend_id
          WHERE flf.user IN ('abc','xyz')
       ) f
  JOIN users mf
    ON mf.id = f.friend_id
 GROUP BY mf.id, mf.name
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
 ORDER BY mf.id, mf.name
```

[**SQL Fiddle here** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b23a5/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b23a5/2)

A more detailed explanation of how we arrive at this is given below. The original queries below assumed that a row in the friend table represented a "one way" relationship, in that "`'abc' ff 'xyz'`" did not imply "`'xyz' ff 'abc'`". But additional comments from the OP hinted that this was not the case.

---

If there is a unique constraint on `friend(user_id,friend_id)`, then one way to get the result would be to get all of the friends of each user, and get a count of rows for that friend. If the count is 2, then we know a particular `friend_id` appears for both user 'abc' and for 'xyz'

```
SELECT mf.id
     , mf.name
  FROM friend f
  JOIN users uu
    ON uu.id = f.user_id
  JOIN users mf
    ON mf.id = f.friend_id
 WHERE uu.name IN ('abc','xyz')
 GROUP BY mf.id, mf.name
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
 ORDER BY mf.id, mf.name
```

(This approach can also be extended to find a mutual friend of three or more users, by including more users in the IN list, and changing the value we compare the COUNT(1) to.

This isn't the only query that will return the specified resultset; there are other ways to get it as well.

---

Another way to get an equivalent result:

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.name
  FROM ( SELECT f1.friend_id
           FROM friend f1
           JOIN users u1
             ON u1.id = f1.user_id
          WHERE u1.name = 'abc'
       ) t1
  JOIN ( SELECT f2.friend_id
           FROM friend f2
           JOIN users u2
             ON u2.id = f2.user_id
          WHERE u2.name = 'xyz'
       ) t2
    ON t2.friend_id = t1.friend_id
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = t1.friend_id
 ORDER BY u.id, u.name
```

---

**NOTES**

These queries do not check whether user 'abc' is a friend of 'xyz' (the two user names specified in the WHERE clause). It is only finding the common friend of both 'abc' and 'xyz'.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The queries above satisfy the specified requirements, and all the examples and test cases provided in the question.

Now it sounds as if you want a row in that relationship table to be considered a "two way" relationship rather than just a "one way" relationship. It sounds like you want to want to consider the friend relationship ('abc','xyz') equivalent to ('xyz','abc').

To get that, then all that needs to be done is to have the query create the inverse rows,, and that makes it easier to query. We just need to be careful that if both those rows ('abc','xyz') and ('xyz','abc') already exist, that we don't create duplicates of them when we invert them.

To create the inverse rows, we can use a query like this. (It's simpler to look at this when we don't have the JOIN to the users table, and we use just the id value:

```
SELECT fr.user_id
     , fr.friend_id 
  FROM friend fr
 WHERE fr.user_id IN (1,2)
 UNION
SELECT fl.friend_id AS user_id
     , fl.user_id AS friend_id
  FROM friend fl
 WHERE fl.friend_id IN (1,2)
```

It's simpler if we don't include the predicates on the user_id and friend_id table, but that could be a very large (and expensive) rowset to materialize.

Comment: hey in this query i get the only result when id is prsent in user_id of friend column but it will not work if i find mutual friend between 'pqr' and 'xyz'

Comment: its hard to make format something like a two-way table.. i suggest you stick to old school and add/point out the already obvious relation like 2 is a friend of 1 .. this is not logic programming so its a bit hard (but not impossible) to do given the data

Comment: @FrancisFuerte: ya i know its a bit hard but my whole application works on that table and if now i change the logic i have to make some bigger changes in my application....so i have to find that solution

Comment: then make use of temporary tables.. query it one way for a temporary table.. and query it another way for another temporary table.. and finally based on those temporary tables get the values that are equal

Comment: @Raj Jagani: it wasn't clear that a row in the `friend` table was considered to be a two-way relationship. (I took the "**one way**" description to mean that `'abc'->'xyz'` was not equivalent to `'xyz'->'abc'`. (My confusion may be because typically think of an describe a "less than" relationship between two integers to be "one way", but an equality relationship is "two way". (a=b is equivalent to b=a, but a<b is not equivalent to b<a). Query in my answer is revised to handle `'abc'->'xyz'` equivalent to `'xyz'->'abc'`, along with a link to a SQL Fiddle demonstration.

Comment: @spencer7593: ya, you are right but my application works in that way if one entry is there `'abc'->'xyz'` than `'abc'` is friend of `'xyz'` and `'xyz'` is friend of `'abc'` now how can i find **mutual friend** in that relationship see i am using following query for finding a friend of particular user

Comment: @spencer7593:ya, you are right i am using that relationship if entry in friend column `'1'->'2'` than **'1' is friend of '2'** and **'2' is a friend of '1'** I am using this query to find a all the friend of particular user  `SELECT u.id,u.name FROM users u WHERE u.id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM friend WHERE friend_id = 1 UNION SELECT friend_id FROM friend WHERE user_id = 1 )`

Comment: @spencer7593: hey spencer i need little more help. see i have third `table collection` and i want `amount` of his each friend you can see the example on this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a680c/1) and you can find the query in the link and if there is no `amount` for any `friend` than it should be `NULL` **You can understand just see this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a680c/1)**(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a680c/1)

Comment: @Raj Jagani:  I think you just need to add the `LEFT` keyword before the `JOIN`, and it looks like you probably want a predicate on the `user_id` column too.  (I think you want the amount for a `friend_id` associated with that `user_id` rather than all rows for `friend_id`.  The `LEFT` keyword makes it an outer join,  in case there are no rows in collection, you still return a row. If you can have more than one row from collection match, you probably want an aggregate either SUM(amount) or MAX(amount)  [SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a680c/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a680c/3)

Comment: @spencer7593: Thank you once again for your help

Comment: @spencer7593: hey spencer once again i am stuck. see i have two more tables `bill` and `bill_person` and i want to find the `number of common bills between user and his friends` and i have try this query but it not show the perfect result. you can see this query in the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd608/1 
In the result of this query you can see that `pqr has showing 2 no_coomon_bills but it should be 1` the problem is it counting other  persons also.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

given that you want to get the mutual friends of friends 1 & 2

```
select friend_id into #tbl1 from users where user_id = 1

select friend_id into #tbl2 from users where friend_id = 2

select id, name from users where id in(select friend_id from #tbl1 f1, #tbl2 f2 where f1.friend_id=f2.friend_id)
```